# C++ projects missing "Device" in deployment options

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, c++-cli, windows-phone-8.1

Creating a new C++ project in Visual Studio 2013 (targeting targeting Windows Phone 8.1), I see that I am unable to deploy to "Device".  The option is missing from the deployment list:

[image: Deployment List VS 2013 missing "Device"]

This problem seems to be unique to C++ projects, because when I create a similar WP8.1 C# project, the "Device" option is present:

[image: "Device" option is present in C# project]

I'm not sure what to do.  Has anyone come across this problem and been able to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discovered the solution about 10 seconds after posting.  It was just a matter of changing the platform from "Win32" to "ARM". `</n00b>`

[image: "Device" appears in the list after changing platform to "ARM"]